# Prevent docking in a WeifenLuo DockPanelSuite tool window

Tags: dockpanel-suite

We have a set of forms which dock into a series of DockPanelSuite tool panels as a pre-defined layout. That aleady works fine for these forms; no problem.

But we also have some large forms which aren't well suited to docking. We would like to set some properties in DockPanelSuite so they neither dock with any other dock pane, nor allow other panes to dock with them.

We want to be able to override this (preferably, easily) -- for example, allowing a floating window to be docked if you Ctrl-drag it onto a tool window.

I've been experimenting with the DockSample sample app.

DockContent.AllowEndUserDocking=false looks promising. It prevents my floater from docking with the main DockPanel. That's good. But it can still dock in tool windows. Bad.

DockContent.Pane.FloatWindow.AllowEndUserDocking=false prevents the floater from docking with any window. More good. But, other floaters (no so marked) may still dock with *it*. Bad, still.

Basically I want to make these floaters say, "I'm not docking with anyone, and no one is docking with me" until I tell it otherwise.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Then why do you want to make it derived from `DockContent`? If you derive it from `Form` then all you want can be achieved.